# Flutter: perfectly align Icons to the edge

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to align the icon to the **very left edge** of the blue container.
The red container is just there for reference (I am using ScreenUtil).
How can I align the icon perfectly to the left edge of the blue container? So that there is no gap, not even one pixel? 
 In this snippet I used FaIcons, however I have the same problem with the standard material icons.

[image: Here you can see the result of my code]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    left: false,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 50.w,
          color: Colors.blue,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.w),
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: 25.w,
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.bars),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.w),
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 20.w,
          height: 20.w,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the padding from iconbutton and set constraints.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    left: false,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.blue,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: 25,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            constraints: BoxConstraints(),
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.person,),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35),
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

[image: here is the result]

Comment: I tried it and still I have the same problem. The padding doesn't set to zero doesn't fix it

Comment: i have fixed it on running app then provided the code here.

Comment: Okay I see what your code did, but my goal is, so that the icon touches the left edge. There is still a small gap in your example. Is this possible?

Comment: yes but not via icon you must use an svg icon for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine

```
Container(
          width: 50.w,
          color: Colors.blue,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.w),
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: 25.w,
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
           ),
        ),
```